# Eigenvalues of a circulant matrix, in descending order

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, circulant-matrices

> Let $C \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ be a circulant matrix. Then its eigenvalues have the form (e.g. [here](http://ee.stanford.edu/~gray/toeplitz.pdf) [PDF], page 32)
>   $$\lambda_k = \sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1} c_j \omega_k^j, \tag1$$
>   where $c = (c_0, c_1, \ldots, c_{n - 1})$ is the first row of $C$ and
>   $$\omega_k = \exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{n} k\right)$$
>   If $C$ is also stochastic, its eigenvalues are in the interval $[-1, 1]$, and one of them is $1$.

I'd like to obtain the second greatest eigenvalue, but unfortunately equation $(1)$ does not give them in sorted order. For example, for
$$c = \frac{1}{3}(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1) \in \mathbb R^{12}$$
the second-greatest eigenvalue is $0.6666$ and is found at $k = 2$. On the other hand, for
$$c = \frac{1}{2}(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1) \in \mathbb R^{12}$$
the second-greatest eigenvalue is $0.8660$ and is found at $k = 1$.

It's not clear how I can sort these sum of exponentials.

Comment: Okay, An interesting observation. Was there a question you had about it?

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yes, I'd like to obtain the second-greatest eigenvalue, as I stated in the segment just after the quoted piece. This does not look straightforward because just substituting $k = 2$ does not work since formula $(1)$ does not yield eigenvalues in a ordered fashion.

Comment: What's wrong with computing the eigenvalues and sorting the list?

Comment: Wintermute beat me to it: FInding the 2nd largest eigenvalue is an $O(n)$ operation, which is likely as good as you'll find.

Comment: @Wintermute I need a closed-form expression unfortunately. I was hoping it was possible to obtain something like that analytically.